# Speed up opencv from python?

Tags: python, opencv, opencl

Have people had success speeding up video (post) processing in python/opencv?

I'm using 4.5.2 from brew on a (non-M1) MacBook Pro.

The two "tall poles" I expect to impact performance are:

- I'm using ndarray types for Mat (the default), so I don't believe
  algorithms can take advantage of OpenCL acceleration.
- VideoCapture looks to be read()'ing in real-time, so I'm limited to 30 fps max
  processing on a 30 fps source.  A few sources suggest with FFMPEG,
  i.e. build from source, would allow reading as fast as the processor
  can run.

What I've seen from online searching (since I'm post-processing) suggest using parallel processing by splitting the file into chunks and reading in a separate thread.  I can look at that.  But I'd also like to understand if people had success fixing the two issues I raised.  Ideally, faster reading and processing would allow me to avoid having to chunk and then combine video snippets...

My initial attempts to convert Mat -> UMat have had no noticeable improvement, even though I can see that OpenCV source has OpenCL implementations for the methods I am using (undistort, cvtColor, calcOpticalFlowFarneback, etc).  FWIW, I'm getting < 5 fps for a 30 fps source.

To summarize:

1. Have people seen improvements from using UMat instead of Mat for OpenCL support?
2. Does a custom build with FFMPEG allow faster than real-time reading with VideoCapture?
3. Suggestion I haven't thought of?

The intent is to use python because of the speed of iteration, so I'm hoping for some easy tricks to speed of the computational step of each iteration.

Comment: "VideoCapture looks to be read()'ing in real-time" --not when reading from files, that wouldn't make much sense (but a lot of beginners here assume it does and try to futilely change the FPS parameter).

Comment: Is there an easy test to demonstrate that?  With a 1msec timeout for keypress, showing the video (with no processing) runs at real-time for me.

Comment: Try it with a lower res video of known frame rate, and don't display, just measure the time for reading. The display itself might be decent overhead. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244613/3962537) I wrote few years back. There I was reading three 1280x800 videos in parallel at ~3ms per frame each. If VideoCapture really is a bottleneck (it's far from perfect) then looking for a better decoder might be a necessity.

Comment: I **have** had speedups from using `UMat` so yes.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for the clarification about VideoCapture not being tied to the fps.  Confirmed on my MacBook.  Thanks for the link to one of your other posts, that was a good read, too!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Have any pointers to examples?  My searches are coming up with a dearth of examples/tips.  I can cut the processing for farneback by about 1/2 with UMat, but I'm not sure if there are ways to pre-allocate and re-use GPU memory (as hinted at here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/?project_name=Kjue%2Fpython-opencv-gpu-video#) or manipulate the UMat to turn the flow into an image.

Comment: not anything at hand, unfortunately. stuff runs asynchronously. a function call probably results in the submission of a kernel execution on the data. returned UMats are promises. you can stick one UMat into another function that runs another kernel... that'll wait for the argument to be calculated. it's all good and safe and regular but things can run in parallel.